# Покрасить элемент внутри кнопки

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Здравствуйте, есть три кнопки, нажимаем по ней, в какой-то цвет красится кружочек, как это можно сделать?

Я совсем новичок, начал делать следующим образом, но дальше - встал в ступор. На том, когда нужно обратиться к `this`, чтобы покрасить ту кнопку, на которой произошло событие.

Но один момент, покрасить нужно не саму кнопку, а абсолютно позиционированный элемент внутри неё, т.е. кружок;

Вот код:

```
var  btn = document.querySelectorAll('.button');

var  change = document.getElementsByClassName('change-element');

function test(){
    for (var index = 0; index<change.length; index++) {
        change[index].style.backgroundColor="black";
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i<btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].addEventListener("click", test);

}
```

Comment: Добавить в стиль solid

Comment: а почему не использовать для этого jQuery?

Comment: @Diefair, потому что метка [tag:javascript]

Answer (score 1):

Может так:

```js
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('.button');

function test() {
  this.getElementsByClassName('change-element')[0].style.backgroundColor = "black";
}

for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener("click", test);

}
```

```css
ul>li {
  list-style: none;
}
.change-element {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="button">Button1 <span class="change-element">111</span>
    </li>
    <li class="button">Button2 <span class="change-element">111</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Но они обе красятся, а должна только та по которой нажал)

Comment: @АлександрВеселов на подобие radio?

Answer (score 1):

Решено:

```
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('.button');

var change = document.getElementsByClassName('change-element');

function test(){
    for (var index = 0; index<change.length; index++) {
        change[index].style.backgroundColor="#95a5a6";
    }
    this.getElementsByClassName('change-element')[0].style.backgroundColor="red";
}



for (var i = 0; i<btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].addEventListener("click", test);
}
```

Comment: А не лучше событие вешать на контейнер, а затем проверять event.target? да и использовать псевдоэлементы для кнопок.